# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render in NextJS using GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, next.js, apollo

I'm putting navbar in my _app.js so I don't need to insert it in every component. My problem is that after I login it outputs an error `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.` and its pointing it on `useQuery(GETCARTDATA`

Pls check my code here

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const token = getToken()
    const [isPopUpShow, setPopUpShow] = useState(false)
    const [cartStateData, setCartStateData] = useState([])
    const [isCartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false)
    let cartDetailsData
    
    if (token) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
      cartDetailsData = useLazyQuery(GETCARTDATA, {
        variables: {
          page: 1
        },
      })
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
      useMemo(() => {
        const cartData = get(cartDetailsData.data, 'findCartDetails.orders') || []
        const cartItems = []
        if (cartData.length) {
          cartData.map(
            itm =>
              itm.lineItems.length &&
              itm.lineItems.map(item => cartItems.push(item))
          )
        }
        setCartStateData(cartItems)
      }, [cartDetailsData.data])
    }
  
    return (
      <>
        <div className="app-outer">
          {token ? (
            <ShowroomHeader
              isPopUpShow={isPopUpShow}
              setPopUpShow={setPopUpShow}
              cartStateData={cartStateData}
              cartDetailsData={cartDetailsData}
              token={token}
            />
          ) : (
            <Navbar />
          )}
        </div>
  
        <div className="main">
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>

      </>
    )
  }
  
  export default withApollo(App)
```

Comment: hooks rule broken - you can't use hooks conditionally ... use `useLazyQuery` (and effect) instead

Comment: show how, update q.

Comment: @xadm. updated.

Comment: start with simple, live (CRA) react (not next) and follow tutorials, **code when you know exactly what you're doing and why this way** ... at least for basic react things ... using FC and hooks requires different (than 'linear') thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@xadmn mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889773/rendered-more-hooks-than-during-the-previous-render-in-nextjs-using-graphql#comment116497801_65889773), you're rendering your hooks conditionally while React expects the same number of hook calls on every render, thus breaking the [rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

You'll need to remove your if statement and move your condition inside a `useEffect` hook, using `useLazyQuery`'s returned function to execute the query from there. You can also move your `useMemo` code to the `onCompleted` callback, since it depends on the results from the query.

```js
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const token = getToken()
    const [isPopUpShow, setPopUpShow] = useState(false)
    const [cartStateData, setCartStateData] = useState([])
    const [isCartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false)

    const [getCardData, cartDetailsData] = useLazyQuery(GETCARTDATA, {
        onCompleted: (data) => {
            const cartData = get(data, 'findCartDetails.orders') || []
            const cartItems = []
            if (cartData.length) {
                cartData.map(
                    itm =>
                        itm.lineItems.length &&
                        itm.lineItems.map(item => cartItems.push(item))
                )
            }
            setCartStateData(cartItems)
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if (token) {
            getCardData({ variables: { page: 1 } })
        }
    }, [token])
  
    return (
        // Your JSX here
    )
}
```